# Mocking slick.dbio.DBIO composition in specs2

Tags: scala, transactions, slick, specs2

Using Scala, Play Framework, Slick 3, Specs2.

I have a *repository* layer and a *service* layer. The repositories are quite dumb, and I use `specs2` to make sure the service layer does its job.

My repositories used to return futures, like this:

```
def findById(id: Long): Future[Option[Foo]] =
  db.run(fooQuery(id))
```

Then it would be used in the service:

```
def foonicate(id: Long): Future[Foo] = {
  fooRepository.findById(id).flatMap { optFoo =>
    val foo: Foo = optFoo match {
      case Some(foo) => [business logic returning Foo]
      case None => [business logic returning Foo]
    }

    fooRepository.save(foo)
  }
}
```

Services were easy to spec. In the service spec, the `FooRepository` would be mocked like this:

```
fooRepository.findById(3).returns(Future(Foo(3)))
```

---

I recently found the need for database transactions. Several queries should be combined into a single transaction. The [prevailing opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265810/2591473) seems to be that it's perfectly ok to handle transaction logic in the service layer.

With that in mind, I've changed my repositories to return `slick.dbio.DBIO` and added a helper method to run the query transactionally:

```
def findById(id: Long): DBIO[Option[Foo]] =
  fooQuery(id)

def run[T](query: DBIO[T]): Future[T] =
  db.run(query.transactionally)
```

The services compose the `DBIO`s and finally call the repository to run the query:

```
def foonicate(id: Long): Future[Foo] = {
  val query = fooRepository.findById(id).flatMap { optFoo =>
    val foo: Foo = optFoo match {
      case Some(foo) => [business logic finally returning Foo]
      case None => [business logic finally returning Foo]
    }

    fooRepository.save(foo)
  }

  fooRepository.run(query)
}
```

That seems to work, but now I can only spec it like this:

```
val findFooDbio = DBIO.successful(None))
val saveFooDbio = DBIO.successful(Foo(3))

fooRepository.findById(3) returns findFooDbio
fooRepository.save(Foo(3)) returns saveFooDbio
fooRepository.run(any[DBIO[Foo]]) returns Future(Foo(3))
```

That `any` in the `run` mock sucks! Now I'm not testing the actual logic but instead accept any `DBIO[Foo]`! I've tried to use the following:

```
fooRepository.run(findFooDbio.flatMap(_ => saveFooDbio)) returns Future(Foo(3))
```

But it breaks with `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`, which is `specs2`'s way of saying "sorry mate, the method with this parameter wasn't found". I've tried various variations, but none of them worked.

I suspect that might be because functions can't be compared:

```
scala> val a: Int => String = x => "hi"
a: Int => String = <function1>
scala> val b: Int => String = x => "hi"
b: Int => String = <function1>
scala> a == b
res1: Boolean = false
```

Any ideas how to spec DBIO composition without cheating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar idea and also investigated it to see if I could:

- create the same DBIO composition
- use it with matcher in mocking

However I found out that it is actually infeasible in practice:

- as you noticed, you cannot compare functions
- additionally, when you investigate internals of DBIO, it is basically Free-monad-like structure - it has implementation for plain values and directly generated queries (then, if [you extract the statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434286/view-sql-query-in-slick) you could compare *some* part of the query), but there are also mappings which stores functions
- even if you somehow managed to reuse functions, so that they had reference equality, implementations of DBIO do not care about overriding `equals`, so they would be different beast anyway

So knowing that, I gave up the initial idea. What I can recommend instead:

- mock on any input of `database.run` - it is more error prone, as it won't notify you if test expectations start differing from returned results, but it's better than nothing
- replace DBIO by some intermediate structure, that you know you can compare safely. E.g. Cats' [Free monad implementation](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Free.scala#L190) uses case classes so as long as you manage to ensure that functions are somehow comparable (e.g. by not creating them ad hoc, but instead using `val`s and `object`s), you could compare on intermediate representation, and mock whole *interpret -> run* process
- replace unit tests with mocked database with integration tests with an actual database
- try out [Typed Tagless Final Interpreter](https://softwaremill.com/free-tagless-compared-how-not-to-commit-to-monad-too-early/) pattern for handling databases - and basically inject in tests different monad than in production (e.g. `prod -> service` returning DBIO, `production -> service` returning Futures you want)

Actually, you could try many other things with Free, TTFI and swapping implementations. The bottom line is - you cannot reliably compare on DBIO, so design your code in a way, that you could test without doing so. It's not a pleasant answer, especially if you just wanted to put together test, and move on, but AFAIK there is no other way.

Comment: Great answer, worth the wait :)